# How to cache data in Spring MVC web application within more HTTP requests?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, caching, spring-mvc

In one my web page (Spring MVC web application) I show a data in many forms (table, chart and another table). Because I load page contents via Ajax requests I don't want to load the same data on every request. The data belongs to one particular logged in user.

Is there in Spring framework some suitable technique / cache handler how to handle this kind of data? I can use for this purpose `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` object but I makes me wonder if is there some better technique.

**Edit:** in the meantime I found a possibility to define `session` scope in definition of my bean and I think it is what I need, isn't it?

```
<bean id="pageDataCache" class="controller.utils.PageDataCache" scope="session">  
<aop:scoped-proxy/>  
</bean>
```

So a new instance will be created for each HTTP Session and will store a data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Spring caching](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html). Spring caching is a caching abstraction which can be implemented by any actual caching provider like ehcache, memcache or ever a plain old java concurrent hash map. And it is very well integrated with the rest of the Spring framework.

Comment: I will check Spring caching. One more question - save data, as I mentioned in my edit, in a bean defined as `scope = session` is a recommended / suitable technique or is not?

Comment: Well, it is equivalent to storing data in `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` which is also session scoped. Spring caching does not have a scope bound to it. You can decide the scope for yourself.